# How to update WSL?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I first installed WSL manually, but want to use a feature [to access linux filesystems](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/access-linux-filesystems-in-windows-and-wsl-2/), and seems it will only work with Insiders.

So I registered my account, went to "Windows Insiders Program" setting and then "Windows Update" section, updated everything and etc

But I don't know how to update wsl to include this new feature.
It still says `--mount` is an invalid option

Comment: There's likely a more efficient way using PowerShell, but one sure way is to disable, then re-enable WSL _(disabling it may cause data loss in the VM, as I'm not sure how/where WSL stores edited files)_: `WinKey`+`R` → _Open_: `OptionalFeatures` → OK → Windows Subsystem Linux

Comment: are you on build build 20211 or newer?

Comment: What do you mean by "installed WSL manually"? Was it not as a Windows feature?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the exact build number you are currently running.

Answer (score 0):

I was on the wrong Insider Channel. On "Beta" the feature wasn't available. Switched to "Dev", updated and restarted again. All working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please remember to accept your answer if it solved your problem